# Select dropdown in Blazor in component fires, but only prior selection option is displayed instead of current selection option

Tags: .net, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I have a Blazor 7 component that is basically a dropdown selection. When a selection is made, an event fires, so the calling page/component can get the selected item. One problem is that, only the previous item is carried over to the parent, not the current selection.  I'm at a loss as how to solve this as everything seems to be working other than this quirk.
Basically, the first time you make a selection, the object passed to the parent is empty (not null). The second time you make a selection, the first item is passed to the parent. A third selection will show the second item and so forth.
Here's the component code:

```
<h3>DropDownNames</h3>

<select @bind="@mySelector.SelectedId" @bind:after="SelectionChanged">
    @foreach (var opt in mySelector.Options)
    {
        <option value="@opt.Id" class="@opt.Style">@opt.Name @(new String('*', @opt.Stars))</option>
    }
</select>

@if (mySelector.SelectedId > 0)
{
    selectedOption = mySelector.Options.Find(e => e.Id == mySelector.SelectedId);
}

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Option> GetSelectedOption { get; set; }

    private Selector mySelector = new Selector(myOptions);

    private Option selectedOption { get; set; } = new Option();

    //populate the select options
    private static List<Option> myOptions = new List<Option>() {
        new Option(1, "Fred", "style3", 2),
        new Option(2, "Joe", "style1", 4),
        new Option(3, "Jana", "style2", 4),
        new Option(4, "Mary", "style1", 3),
        new Option(5, "Howard", "style3", 1) };

    async void SelectionChanged()
    {
        await GetSelectedOption.InvokeAsync(selectedOption);
    }

    public class Selector
    {
        public Selector(List<Option> options) => Options = options;

        public int SelectedId { get; set; } = 0;
        public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public Option(int id = 0, string? name = "", string? style = "", int stars = 0)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Style = style;
            Stars = stars;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Style { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
    }


}
```

and the parent page (just the index page):

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<DropDownNames GetSelectedOption="getSelectedOption"></DropDownNames>

<br />

<p>You selected: @selectedOption.Id</p>
<p>@selectedOption.Name has @selectedOption.Stars.ToString() stars</p>


@code {

    DropDownNames.Option selectedOption = new DropDownNames.Option();
    public void getSelectedOption(DropDownNames.Option option)
    {
        selectedOption = option;
    }
}
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong here, but not sure where to start/look. Bing's AI was no help as it generates unusable code, so seeking help from real people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (mySelector.SelectedId > 0)
{
    selectedOption = mySelector.Options.Find(e => e.Id == mySelector.SelectedId);
}
```

The way you're changing the `selectedOption` field is causing the issue here. It's being executed after the `EventCallback` is invoked.

You should move that logic to the `SelectionChanged()` method, right before the  `EventCallback` is invoked.

```
async Task SelectionChanged()
{
    selectedOption = mySelector.Options.Find(e => e.Id == mySelector.SelectedId);
    await GetSelectedOption.InvokeAsync(selectedOption);
}
```

Comment: OMG - I completely missed that! Thanks!